# Is it correct to store RSA public key to .env file? If yes, how to store it with multiple line? otherwise, why?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

Why am I consistently getting the error message "**Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements**" when using my own public key with `crypto.subtle.importKey`, but not with a generated public key?

```js
// assuming this store in .env
const PUBLIC_KEY='-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDRixgfjY2/zdJ18OnwSiVzmBKCh5GYzfvX2jYlLC3DHfGstnbL0fxnHxizg68ZG4oQPfmKJQGF2hbQ+vQ+zaYfC33mKZGF+ln+NlxQk+D742pj5GYenIPjKHshV3P1GHubAw9nW71WAd0yyjL7BHV3nWbewR+AAce8V6YLt54mVwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'


function formatToPEM(derCertificate, type) {
  const pemHeader=`-----BEGIN ${type || ""}-----\n`
  const pemFooter=`-----END ${type || ""}-----`
  let binary = "";
  const derArray = new Uint8Array(derCertificate);
  for (let i in derArray) binary += String.fromCharCode(derArray[i]);
  const pemContents = `${btoa(binary)}\n`;
  return pemHeader+pemContents+pemFooter
}

function formatToDER(pemCertificate, type) {
  const pemHeader=`-----BEGIN ${type || ""}-----`
  const pemFooter=`-----END ${type || ""}-----`
  const pemContents=pemCertificate.replace(pemHeader, '').replace(pemFooter, '').replace(/\\r\\n/g, '')
  const contentDecoded = atob(pemContents)
  const derArray = new Uint8Array(contentDecoded.length)
  for (let i in contentDecoded) derArray[i] = contentDecoded.charCodeAt(i)
  return derArray
}

async function encrypt(algorithm, data, selfOwnedPubKey) {
  let key
  if (selfOwnedPubKey) {
    const pubKeySelfOwnedPEM = selfOwnedPubKey
    const pubKeySelfOwnedDER = formatToDER(pubKeySelfOwnedPEM, 'PUBLIC KEY')
    crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "spki",
        pubKeySelfOwnedDER,
        {
            name: algorithm,
            modulusLength: 1024,
            publicExponent: new Uint8Array(0x01, 0x00, 0x01),
            hash: 'SHA-256',
        },
        true,
        ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
    )
    .then(importedKey => key = importedKey)
    .catch(error=>{
        console.group(error)
        console.log('code: ', error.code)
        console.log('message: ', error.message)
        console.log('name: ', error.name)
        console.groupEnd()
    })
    
    console.group('---SELF_OWNED_KEY---')
    console.log('pubKeySelfOwnedPEM:\n',);
    console.log(`%c${PUBLIC_KEY}`,'color:green;font-weight:bold')
    console.log('pubKeySelfOwnedDER: ', pubKeySelfOwnedDER)
    console.groupEnd();
  } else {
    let keyPair = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: algorithm,
            modulusLength: 1024,
            publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1,0,1]),
            hash: 'SHA-256',
        },
        true,
        ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
    );
    let pubKeyGeneratedExportedDER = new Uint8Array(await crypto.subtle.exportKey('spki',keyPair.publicKey))
    const pubKeyGeneratedPEM = formatToPEM(pubKeyGeneratedExportedDER, 'PUBLIC KEY')
    key = keyPair.publicKey;
    
    console.group('---GENERATED_KEY---')
    console.log('pubKeyGeneratedOriginal:',keyPair.publicKey);// CryptoKey: Object
    console.log('pubKeyGeneratedExportedDER:',pubKeyGeneratedExportedDER);// ArrayBuffer: TypedArray
    console.log('pubKeyGeneratedPEM:\n');// formatPEM: String
    console.log(`%c${pubKeyGeneratedPEM}`,'color:green;font-weight:bold');
    console.groupEnd()
  }

  const cipher = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
      name: algorithm
    },
    key,
    data
  );
  return cipher
};

// encode plain text
const plainText='text';
const encoder = new TextEncoder()
const encodedText = encoder.encode(plainText);

encrypt('RSA-OAEP', encodedText)
  .then(chiper=>console.log('encrypted!'))
  .catch(error=>console.log(error))
  
encrypt('RSA-OAEP', encodedText, PUBLIC_KEY)
  .then(chiper=>console.log('encrypted!'))
  .catch(error=>console.log(error))
```

I suspect that the public key is invalid. So I've tried using generatedKey from code above

```
encrypt('RSA-OAEP', plainTextEncoded, /*process.env.PUBLIC_KEY*/)
```

The result is as expected (plainText encrypted). If that is indeed the case, how you store it to ensure that data 'meet requirement'?

Comment: PEM format is standard,

Comment: @BGPHiJACK is it invalid format? how to store it with new line?

Comment: If it's a client application, everything you put in `.env` is still visible to the user

Answer (score 0):

USE node-rsa

```
//create cipher node rsa
const cipher = new nodeRSA({ b: 512 });
const keyPrivate = key.private;
const pubKey = key.public;

cipher.importKey(pubKey, "pkcs1-public");
const text = password
const encrypted = cipher.encrypt(text, "base64");

const decipher = new nodeRSA(keyPrivate, "pkcs1");
const decrypted = decipher.decrypt(encrypted, "utf8");

console.log("decrypted: ", decrypted);

return setPasswordEncrypt(encrypted);
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).